# Form not validating in Symfony 2.8

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony, symfony-2.8

I have a Symfony 2.8 based proejct, and I have a form, created with `CraueFormFlowBundle`, which allows creation of multi-step forms. I created my flow class, and intermediary form types for each step, everything works at this level. The only thing that is not working is that not a single validation rule is triggered, whether between each step or at the end of the form flow. I'm using annotations in my entities to validate data. I've checked in my `config.yml` that both `validation` and `form` components are `enabled` and `framework.validation.enable_annotations` is set to `true`.

Here's my controller :

```
public function newEvaluationAction(Classroom $classroom, Subject $subject, Period $period)
{
    $evaluation = $this->getSchoolManager()->createEvaluation($classroom, $subject, $period);

    $flow = $this->get('app.form.flow.evaluation_create');
    $flow->bind($evaluation);

    $form = $flow->createForm();

    if ($flow->isValid($form)) {
        $flow->saveCurrentStepData($form);

        if ($flow->nextStep()) {
            $form = $flow->createForm();
        } else {
            $this->getSchoolManager()->persistEvaluation($evaluation);
            $this->redirectToRoute('ec_classroom_show_subject', [
                'subject' => $subject->getId()
            ]);
        }
    }

    return $this->render('classrooms/subjects/evaluations/new.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'flow' => $flow,
        'classroom' => $classroom,
        'subject' => $subject,
        'period' => $period,
        'evaluation' => $evaluation
    ]);
}
```

and my `Evaluation` entity

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(
 *     repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\EvaluationRepository"
 * )
 */
class Evaluation
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(max=255)
     */
    private $label;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     * @Assert\Date()
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var Collection
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Knowledge")
     * @Assert\Count(min=1, minMessage="evaluation.knowledges.at_least_one")
     */
    private $knowledges;

    /**
     * @var Collection|Scale[]
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Scale", mappedBy="evaluation", cascade={"ALL"})
     * @Assert\Count(min=1, minMessage="evaluation.scales.at_least_one")
     * @Assert\Valid(traverse=true)
     */
    private $scales;

    /**
     * @var Subject
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Subject")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $subject;

    /**
     * @var Period
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Period")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $period;

    /**
     * @var Classroom
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Classroom")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $classroom;

    /**
     * @var Composition[]|Collection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Composition", mappedBy="evaluation", cascade={"all"})
     * @Assert\Valid(traverse=true)
     */
    private $compositions;
```

They are more entities to validate (see relationships in the `Evaluation` entity), but not even the `Evaluation`  itself, without associations, is not validated. What can I do to have every validation rule to be checked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution : `CraueFormFlowBundle` creates, for each step of the flow, a validation group name. In my case, the validation group of the 1st step for my `createEvaluation` flow (the name given by the `getName` method of the flow) is named `flow_evaluation_create_step1`. I had to set, in the `Assert` annotation, the `groups` property for the rights fields to validate (ie. the one who are edited in the current step).